# Actualizar un array de documento en mongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy intentando actualizar un documento en una base de datos MongoDB usando *Mongoose*, en el cual tengo el siguiente Schema:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const userSchema = new Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  historial: [String]
});
```

Compruebo si el usuario existe, si existe actualizo los datos en el documento del usuario correspondiente al `_id` de la consulta. El problema es que cada vez que actualizo para añadir un elemento al historial, me lo reemplaza, en vez de añadir el nuevo elemento.

```
router.post('/remember', isAuthenticated, async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.user._id;
  let user = await User.findById(id)
  const { frase } = req.body;
  user.historial = frase
  await user.save();
});
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al actualizar el campo *historial* vaya añadiendo elementos, en vez de borrar los datos antiguos y sobreescribir por los nuevos?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para actualizar los elementos del `Array` en el campo *historial* de tu documento, debes crear una copia de tu documento, y usar el método `.push()` para añadir los datos nuevos. Además, es necesario que tu petición *http* sea del tipo *PUT* o *PATCH*.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea actualizar el campo *historial* de un documento en MongoDB usando Mongoose. El campo *historial* es de tipo `Array`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para actualizar un campo de tipo `Array` usaremos el método `push()`. Por otra parte, cuando se realizan [operaciones CRUD](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) sobre objetos, se debe usar la [petición *HTTP*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) adecuada. Por norma general, *POST* se utiliza para crear un nuevo documento, en cambio *PUT* y *PATCH* son peticiones usadas para actualizar un elemento ya existente.

Dicho esto, tu controlador pudiese quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
router.put('/remember', isAuthenticated, async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.user._id;
  let user = await User.findById(id);
  const { frase } = req.body;
  user.historial.push(frase);
  console.log(user.historial); // <= puedes verificar aquí que se ha actualizado el campo
  await user.save();
});
```

Espero que con esto aclares las dudas y soluciones el problema.